# Why aren't lost souls and arcade mode available?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

I beat all 20 episodes of Story ~1607 A.D. but no new game modes are available.

What should beating the Story unlock? How can I unlock more modes?

Comment: I changed your question to make it a little more clear, you are free to edit it again if you feel I changed it too much.

Answer (score 1):

[image: What you should see]

Arcade mode is open from the start. Legendary Souls mode should be unlocked for you if you beat story mode. **They are both listed under Offline Play.**

[Here's what the menu looks like on a default setup](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqoithCnQ48&t=2m27s)

I can suggest running story mode again with default settings to see if that helps. [Legendary Souls is alternatively unlocked at Player Level 29](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/630214-soulcalibur-v/answers?qid=311492) so you can try that if a second run of story mode doesn't help.

Additionally, [throughout story mode, you should unlock](http://soulcalibur.wikia.com/wiki/Soulcalibur_V_secrets):

> ```
> Unlock                                Episode to Complete     or Player Level
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Ancient Citadel: Peacetime                    4                       7
> Soul Calibur (Patroklos)                      4                       9
> Unknown Forest: Dark Night                    7                       21
> Soul Edge (Veiled) (Nightmare)                11                      9
> α Patroklos                                   12                      15
> Soul Calibur (α Patroklos)                        Unlock α Patroklos
> Entelechia (α Patroklos)                          Unlock α Patroklos
> Hidden Fang (α Patroklos)                         Unlock α Patroklos
> Asherah (α Patroklos)                             Unlock α Patroklos
> Kuzukiri & Mekki-Maru (Natsu)                 15                      9
> Kali-Yuga (Xiba)                              15                      9
> Denever Castle: Assualt                       18                      18
> Last Rites on the Battleground                18                      40
> Edge Master                                   16                      19
> Tower of Glory: Spiral of Good and Evil           Unlock Edge Master
> The Master (Edge Master)                          Unlock Edge Master
> Pyrrha Ω                                      19                      23
> Denever Castle: Eye of Chaos                      Defeat Pyrrha Ω
> Soul Edge (Pyrrha Ω)                              Unlock Pyrrha Ω
> Soul Edge & Elk Shield (Pyrrha Ω)                 Unlock Pyrrha Ω
> Gladiatrix (Pyrrha Ω)                             Unlock Pyrrha Ω
> Aeneas (Pyrrha Ω)                                 Unlock Pyrrha Ω
> Elysium                                       20                      27
> Utopia of the Blessed                             Defeat Elysium
> Soul Calibur (Elysium)                            Unlock Elysium
> ```

You may unlock other equipment for the unlockable characters when you unlock those characters, depending upon your player level.

The only "mode" to unlock besides Legendary Souls mode is the "Extra" route in Arcade mode which changes your camera angle. "Extra" route unlocks when you reach Player Level 17.